# Combine list of list into map using stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to convert a pojo object that looks like

```
[
  {
    "type": "Preferred",
    "ids": ["A", "B", "C"]
   },
  {
    "type": "Non-preferred",
    "ids": ["D", "E"]
  },
  {
    "type": "Popular",
    "ids": ["A", "D"]
  }
]
```

into `Map<String, List<String>>`, such as:

```
{
 "A": ["Preferred", "Popular"],
 "B": ["Preferred"],
 "C": ["Preferred"],
 "D": ["Non-preferred", "Popular"],
 "E": ["Non-preferred"],
}
```

how can I accomplish this using stream? I preferably want to utilize stream into `collect()`, instead of using `forEach()` (which is basically a for-loop).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The pojo class looks something like:

```
class Pojo {
 String type;
 List<String> ids;
}
```

And I basically have `List<Pojo>`

Comment: Isn't that just a JSON file? Have you tried using a JSON parser?

Comment: It's a java pojo class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using stream, create entry for each type and id combination and then do a group by

```
Map<String, List<String>> results = lists.stream()
            .flatMap(obj->obj.getIds()
                    .stream()
                    .map(id->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(id,obj.getType())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,Collectors.toList())));
```